# Ionic Cordova - Ajax calls not working on IOS but o.k. on Android

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I followed the instructions found here to the letter. It works perfectly on Android, and in my chrome browser (ionic server), but not on IOS emulator, or my IOS devices. I've search for answers but I simply cannot figure out what is wrong. The emulator log isn't showing any errors unless I'm missing something..

https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-wordpress-client/

When I load the app on IOS I get the message:  "Loading Data" but it never goes away. So it's never gets to load.dismiss().

let loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Loading Data...'
    });
    await loading.present();

```
this.wp.getPosts().subscribe(res => {
  this.count = this.wp.totalPosts;
  this.posts = res;
  loading.dismiss();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reaching out to a vendor I work for and had their developers help me out.

The solution was to implement a custom network library (ionic-native-http-connection-backend) that uses the native http client on ios instead of the XHR client to make network requests , this bypasses the cross origin resource sharing, or CORS, restrictions imposed by the iOS webview component

https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend

Once this was implemented everything worked great.